# Meaning of "Leave the graphics context in any state"

Tags: core-graphics, core-text

I use "Core Text" function `CTLineDraw`. But looks like it has some side effect on `CGContextRef`: filling rectangles does not work any more after `CTLineDraw` for the same context (but works before or if I commented out `CTLineDraw` call).

According to [`CTLineDraw`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1511145-ctlinedraw?language=objc) and some other functions in "Core Text" docs:

> This call can leave the graphics context in any state and does not
>   flush the context after the draw operation.

I think this may be related. But what exactly does this sentence means? What I should save & restore context state (this helps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should [save the state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456156-cgcontextsavegstate?language=objc) before the first call to `CTLineDraw` you’re doing and [restore it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455391-cgcontextrestoregstate?language=objc) after the last one. What that line in the documentation means is that Core Text sets various bits of the state internally to do the text drawing you’re asking it to do and doesn’t automatically set them back afterwards.